Regenerating a 4-Year-Old Bitcoin Address Created by BRD Wallet using bip-utils
I have a Bitcoin wallet that I originally created 4 years ago using the BRD wallet app, which has since became the Coinbase Wallet app. I'm playing around with this wallet for educational purposes, it doesn't contain significant funds so I am not afraid of making mistakes.
I have the recovery passphrase for this wallet and have successfully regenerated (in a python script; using bip-utils) the exact same Bech32 address (starting with 'bc1') that I currently see in the Coinbase Wallet app. This confirms that my recovery phrase is correct.
However, I am struggling with regenerating an older P2PKH address (starting with '1') that I used back then for receiving transactions. Despite generating thousands of addresses across multiple accounts (1000 addresses for 1000 different accounts), I haven't been able to reproduce this specific P2PKH address.
from bip_utils import Bip39SeedGenerator, Bip44, Bip44Coins, Bip44Changes

def explore_addresses(mnemonic, account=0, num_addresses=20):
    # Generate seed from mnemonic
    seed = Bip39SeedGenerator(mnemonic).Generate()

    # Generate wallet
    bip44_mst = Bip44.FromSeed(seed, Bip44Coins.BITCOIN)
    bip44_acc = bip44_mst.Purpose().Coin().Account(account)
    bip44_ext = bip44_acc.Change(Bip44Changes.CHAIN_EXT)

    # Interate addresses within the specified account
    addresses = []
    for i in range(num_addresses):
        address = bip44_ext.AddressIndex(i).PublicKey().ToAddress()
        addresses.append((i, address))

    return addresses


mnemonic = '<my recovery phrase from coinbasewallet>'
for account in range(1000):
    addresses = explore_addresses(mnemonic, account, num_addresses=1000)
    for index, address in addresses:
        if address.startswith('12vHA'):
            print(f"Index {index}: {address}")


What might I be missing in regenerating the old P2PKH address?
Are there specific derivation paths or wallet configurations used by BRD that differ from the standard BIP44 path?
I appreciate any insights on how I can successfully regenerate the specific P2PKH address.

Your older P2PKH wallet may not be a hierarchical deterministic wallet(HD wallt).What you need to do is, just print('0x' + seed.hex()), and then import the seed directly into your wallet as a private key with WIF format.
$ git clone https://github.com/mohanson/pybtc
$ cd pybtc

import btc
btc.config.current = btc.config.mainnet

prikey = btc.core.PriKey(int.fromhex('YOUR SEED', 16))
print('WIFs', prikey.wif())
p2pkh_address = btc.core.address_p2pkh(prikey.pubkey())
print('Addr', p2pkh_address)

You can run this script offline.
